# Jquery make form submit wait for response from function call

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I want to add a confirm dialogue to on submit.  I am using [this](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) library which works very well in most cases, but when I use it on forms I can't seem to make the form wait for a response from this.  I'm sure it has something to do with how I'm calling the confirm function, but am not exactly sure why

```
 $('#process_quote').submit(function(){
            $.confirm({
                text: "Would you like to enter shipping information for this quote?",
                confirm: function(button) {
                    $('input[name=enter_shipping]').val(1);
                },
                cancelButton: "No",
                cancel: function(button) {
                    $('input[name=enter_shipping]').val(0);
                }

            });

            return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your confirmation to a button click handler. Then when you have your user confirmation make the submit request.

```
$('button.trigger').on("click", function(){
        $.confirm({
            text: "Would you like to enter shipping information for this quote?",
            confirm: function(button) {
                $('input[name=enter_shipping]').val(1);
                $("#process_quote").submit();
            },
            cancelButton: "No",
            cancel: function(button) {
                $('input[name=enter_shipping]').val(0);
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there something more to it? I gave my button an id of submit_button and for some reason it doesn't even trigger the dialogue ? It states theat submit_button has no method click

Comment: You need to pass the event and add event.preventDefault().  It works fine for the alert, but won't prevent the submit without it.  Thanks for the help, just edit it and I'll check it as best answer.

Comment: The submit doesn't happen until explicitly calling `$("process_quote").submit()` *unless* you have attached the click to a submit button or a button *inside* the form -- in which case the default submit will occur.